# How do you find out if a MUX is bidirectional

Tags: multiplexer, bidirectional

I've used this [MC74VHC157](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC74VHC157-D.PDF) in a project thinking this would be bidirectional but I'm not sure. How do you find out if any MUX is bidirectional?

Comment: You look at the logic diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet shows that the pins are distinct inputs/outputs:

[image: MC74VHC157]

What you search is usually called an *analog switch*, and the datasheet would show a symbolic switch (e.g., [NLAS1053](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NLAS4053-D.PDF)) or the actual implementation, an N-channel/P-channel FET combination (e.g., [SN74LVC1G3157](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn74lvc1g3157)):

[image: NLAS1053]
          
[image: SN74LVC1G3157]

Comment: Thanks this helps. I misquoted the part # that I'm using and in fact the one I'm using is [74LVC1G3157](http://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G3157.pdf) from NXP. The datasheet here does not show the actual implementation but the logic diagram does show the bidirectional feature (I think!).

Comment: Figures 1 and 2 of Nexperia's 74LVC1G3157 datasheet are essentially identical to the ones shown here. (The "bow tie" symbol is just another way of representing a [transmission gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate).)

Answer (score 2):

Digital mulltiplexers are almost certainly uni-directional.  Analog multiplexers probably are bidirectional.

However, studying the datasheets should tell you for sure.

The 74xx157 is clearly a uni-directional digital multiplexer, as shown by the logic diagram in the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

Its unidirectional, anything with gates is one way. There are some digital logic ic's with pull down logic that is bidirectional, ususally they will advertise the bus that it works for (like I2C)

Not all analog muxes are bidirectional, the ones that aren't show input and output and usually have a pmos and nmos.

Bidirectional muxes (switches) will usually have a picture of a switch on the block diagram in the datasheet.

Comment: Would something like the [NC7SB3257](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/NC7SB3257-1011442.pdf) be a bidirectional then? It does say MUX/DEMUX.

Comment: It looks like it. The logic diagram looks like it and it says Vswitch. I'd get it and try it or ask a company rep.